# onchange event on react select trigger only by clicking

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an `<select>` in my react app

```
<select onChange={ e=>{this.setState({selectedValue:e.target.value})} }>
    {this.state.someArr.map( val => <option value={val}> something </option>) }
</select>
```

now if `someArr` in the state changes , it cause the new options rendered inside select element
but `onchange` not triggered and `selectedValue` inside the state remains untouched
how can i overcome this issue? i want new value to set automatically

[HERE IS JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pusoma/edit?js,output)

Comment: Have you tried 'onChange' (camelCase)?

Comment: yeah , i've used camelCase one . thats my typo error in question

Comment: setting the value prop on select might work: `<select value={this.state.selectedValue} ...>`

Comment: @Vijay i think that i've explained my issue incorrect . i've added jsbin . please take a look at jsbin link

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when using React you should never pass an arrow function because it passes different instance each time and can cause unnecessary rendering.

The reason it doesnt work, is because you're trying to access the event in the setState function and you cant do that.

Here is what you should do:

```
export default class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedValue: '',
            someArr: []
        };
    }

    onChange(e) {
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
    }

    render () {
        return <select onChange={this.onChange}}>
                {this.state.someArr.map( val => <option value={val}> something </option>) }
            </select>   
    }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your good advice but that's not worked yet. the problem is when you change `someArr` , new options gets rendered in the select element, but `onChange` never gets called unless user clicks on some options . but i want `onChange` called automatically after new options rendered

Comment: You can try passing the index to each option using the second argument of the map function and store the selectedIndex in your state, and when the array changes, recaculate the selected value according to the index.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `value` prop properly.

```
<select value={this.state.selectedValue} onChange={ e=>{this.setState({selectedValue:e.target.value})} }>
    {this.state.someArr.map( val => <option value={val}> something </option>) }
</select>
```

I hope this works for you.